# jquery post data to jsp page not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

Here is my javascript. I am trying to get a json object from the getData.jsp. But the post is not working. The getData.jsp page is not being called by ajax. Please help me i dont know where i am doing wrong.

"

```
        var queryObject=""; 
        var queryObjectLen="";
        $.ajax({
      url :'getData.jsp', 
            type :'POST',                 
            dataType:'json', 
            success:function(data) { 
                queryObject = eval('(' + JSON.stringify(data) + ')'); 
                queryObjectLen = queryObject.empdetails.length; 
            }, 
            error : function(xhr, type) { 
                alert('server error occoured') 
            } 
        });
        "
```

Here is my getData.jsp

"
                <%@ page import="com.mydb" %>
            <%@page import="org.json.JSONObject" %>
            <%@ include file="../../../lib/util.inc" %>

```
                        <% 
                        log.debug("out.jsp1");
                        mydb db = null;
                        List<JSONObject> empdetails = new LinkedList<JSONObject>();

                        JSONObject responseObj = new JSONObject();

                        try {
                        log.debug("out.jsp");
                        db = new mydb(application);
                        PreparedStatement p_stmt = null;  
                        ResultSet       rs = null;



                        String mySql2 = "select category as category, kb_sum as KB_SUM  FROM mytable ";

                        PreparedStatement p_stmt = db.getPreparedStatement(mySql2);
                        rs = db.executeQuery(p_stmt);
                        JSONObject empObj = null;

                        while (rs.next()) {
                          String name = rs.getString("category");
                         int empid = rs.getInt("KB_SUM");
                         empObj = new JSONObject();
                         empObj.put("name", name);
                         empObj.put("empid", empid);
                         empdetails.add(empObj);
                     }
                         responseObj.put("empdetails", empdetails);
                        out.print(responseObj.toString());
                        rs = null;

                        }

        catch (Exception e) {

                String errorStr = e.getMessage();
                log.error(errorStr);
                out.println(formatPageError(e));


        }
        finally {
                if (db != null) {
                db.freeConnection();
                db = null;
                }


        }

                        %>
```

"

Comment: Have you tested it with an absolute URL?

Comment: I ran my getData.jsp. My JSON is absolutely fine. i tried using same url for  $.ajax({ but getting blank page.

Comment: Thanks everyone..I fixed my problem. It was JSON.stringify(data) not executing in IE8, i add <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" /> to my code. Now it workes prefectly.

Answer (score 0):

type post is not necessary here because you call directly a jsp page.
Try to remove it.

Comment: I removed the POST, still the same problem.

Comment: try with a txt simple file first, if it's work your jsp page doesn't execute (see this example : http://www.jqplot.com/tests/data-renderers.php at bottom of the page)